# While loop only executing once

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a form that displays contact email addresses in text boxes, and drop down selections for titles for those corresponding emails.

TitleSelect1  Email1
TitleSelect2  Email2 ....

the emails have a title_id set, and the select list selects the existing Title. This works fine for the first contact, but the rest will only display the email address, the title dropdown is empty.

```
<?php

while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($Contact_list)) {
    ?>
<tr>
    <td align="right"><select id="Contacts_title" name="Contacts_title[]">
        <?

        while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($title_list)) { //put the contact titles into an array

            if ($row3['title_id'] == $row2['title_id']) {
                ?>
                <option value="<? echo $row3['title_id'] ?>" selected="true"><? echo $row3['title'] ?>!</option>';
                <?
            }

            else {
                ?>
                <option value="<? echo $row3['title_id'] ?>"><? echo $row3['title'] ?> </option>';
                <?
            }
        }

        ?>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td align="left"><input type="text" id="Contacts" name="Contacts[]" value="<? echo $row2['email'] ?>"/></td>
</tr>
<?
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: I usually comment people about their lack of indention. You sir managed to do the opposite.

Comment: Lack of `<?php some_statement: ?> ... <?php endsome_statement; ?>` make baby Skeet cry.

Comment: that code appears to be OK at first glance.. check your $title_list query and make sure you don't have a limit 1 or something else inhibiting your query. Try executng that query from mysql directly and see if it returns all results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array()` only goes through the results of a given query once. Since you're not executing the title_list query every time though your contact list loop, it's still at the end of the query results when you start every iteration after the first.

What you need to do is take all the results from your title_list query, put them into an array, and iterate over *that* for each of your contacts.

---

Here's a general example of how you'd do this (with extraneous bits trimmed out):

```
$contact_list = //some query
$title_list = //some query

$titles = array();
while($title_ar = mysql_fetch_array($title_list)) {
  $titles[] = $title_ar;
}

while($contact_ar = mysql_fetch_array($contact_list)) {
    // some stuff
    foreach($titles as $title) {
        // do something with each title
    }
}
```

Comment: Is a foreach loop the best way to do this?

Comment: A `foreach` loop is one easy way to iterate over an array, yes.

Comment: ok, so use a foreach  to put the title_list into an array, then use that inside the While loop for Contact_list to get the correct output?

Comment: No - use a `while` loop to pull the title_list into an array, then use a `foreach` loop inside the `while` loop for the contact_list to get the correct output. See my edited-in example.

Answer (score 0):

you should put the rows in a variable and echo that after the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

once the inner while loop executes once fully, you wont get any more values in that `mysql_fetch_array` call again. Since the cursor reached the end of rows.

You should store the results of the inner while loop into a php array and then iterate through this array every time within the inner while loop.

Comment: Better yet, he should use PDO and be over with those silly functions.

Comment: yes, but clearly the OP is just beginning with the nuances of php and mysql

Comment: Precisely. Instead of learning about mysql, people should learning the correct way (if not PDO than AT LEAST MySQLi) to begin with.